# Create Table of all Sums from two Arrays in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I got two arrays:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [5,10]
```

Now i want to create a Dataframe from the arrays which hold the sum of all combinations:

```
pd.DataFrame([[6,7,8], [11,12,13]],
                        columns=['1', '2', '3'],
                        index=['5', '10'])
```

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |

I know this can be easily done by iterating over the arrays, but I guess there is a built-in function to accomplish the same but way faster.
I've already looked in the documentation of different functions like the [merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with addition then build the resulting DataFrame by assigning the `index` and `column` names from the lists:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [5, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(arr1) + np.array(arr2)[:, None], index=arr2, columns=arr1
)
```

Or with [`add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) + [`outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) (which works if `arr1` and `arr2` are lists or arrays):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(arr2, arr1), index=arr2, columns=arr1)
```

---

*Note if `arr1` and `arr2` are already arrays (instead of `list`) it can just look like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([5, 10])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr1 + arr2[:, None], index=arr2, columns=arr1)
```

All ways produce `df`:

```
     1   2   3
5    6   7   8
10  11  12  13
```